# find a single document with play+reactivemongo

Tags: playframework, reactivemongo

function that receives an author object in the request

```
  def login = Action.async (parse.json) {
    request => 
      request.body.validate[Author].map {
        author => 
          val query = Json.obj("username" -> "222")
          val obj = collection.find(query).one[Author]
          obj.map {
           author => 
            Ok("Welcome").withSession (
              "username" -> "ok")
          }
      }.getOrElse(Future.successful(BadRequest("invalid json")))
  }
```

always results in a bad request, even with hard coded username. What's wrong here?

Comment: What does your request look like? Do you successfully get past the `validate` step?

Comment: Is there anyway to test if I'm using Play Activator?

Comment: Println doesn't seem to print to console.

Comment: `play.Logger.debug()`

Comment: Where is the log file? is it hidden somewhere

Comment: Should print to console.

Comment: Shows nothing here. Is there a special way to make that work?

Answer (score 0):

Changed login to a post. Seems to be working now.

```
POST    /author/login               @controllers.Authors.login
```